# .htaccess not working in raspberry pi 4 model B

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have recently gone into a raspberry pi instead of the windows 10 computer I was using with xampp and my .htaccess file does not work with same apache, mysql and php. Also I have included the rewrite module and included:

```
<Directory /var/www/>   
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride All   
    Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

So I think it must be on the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./Index.php
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`?

Comment: `./Index.php` does not make much sense, it probably should be `index.php`.

Comment: 1. Is the location of the htaccess file /var/www/.htaccess? 2. Is the line with Index.php supposed to have a capital I on index.php? 3. What 'doesn't work' – does it just not remove index.php? 4. Try replacing your last line with this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1` – note parentheses, $1 and no capital i

Comment: Thank you very much arkascha and Andy Mardell, the problem was with the capital letter. I changed the file name and the reference in the .htaccess and it worked.